# commit and its affect on lock table in exclusive mode nowait

Tags: sql, c, oracle

I have multiprocessing C program use oracle PL/SQL,
The parent process should lock the table

```
lock table tbl1 in exclusive mode nowait;
```

and childs can ONLY commit .

the children are running in the same session , i noticed that if the parent locked the table and the child commit work , the locking was released ! as i know the commit is per transaction while locking is on schema level , is that correct . Also i need to prevent another instance of the same program from running at the same time

if the childs commit work , does that means locking on the table will be released ?

Note : i need to prevent another instance of the program from running by check if the table is locked then exit.

Answer (score 1):

That architecture doesn't make sense.  If the children are running in separate sessions, they'd have no way to use a lock acquired by the parent.  If the children are running in the same session than the first child to commit will release the lock.

If the goal is merely to prevent two instances of the same application from running at the same time, use the [`dbms_lock.request`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#i1002556) method to acquire a custom lock.  Something like

```
l_success := dbms_lock.request( lockhandle => 'MyProcess' );
```

Your parent process can happily hold that lock while the children do whatever they want and then release the lock when all the children complete.

Comment: the children are running in the same session , i noticed that if the parent locked the table and the child commit work , the locking was released ! as i know the commit is per transaction while locking is on schema level , is that correct  .
Also i need to prevent another instance of the same program from running at the same time as u mentioned by checking if the table is locked or not.
I am not familiar with dbms_lock.request  . i will check if i can use it in PL/SQL.
Thanks

Comment: @AhmadAmer - Locks are held by the session.  As I said in my answer, if the children are running in the same session then the first child to commit will release the lock.  It's a bit weird to use the same database session for each of the children in a multithreaded program-- normally the point of multithreading is to allow each child to interact with the database separately.  Perhaps in your case the vast majority of the time is spent running some sort of processing in the C program and database interactions are a small enough part of the performance that sharing a connection works.

Answer (score 0):

Commit (or rollback) will release the lock.

[LOCK TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9015.htm#SQLRF01605) documentation says:

> A locked table remains locked until you either commit your transaction or roll it back, either entirely or to a savepoint before you locked the table.

---

Note that lock will be released if user - who locked the table - commits, not if *anyone else* commits. Their commit (if that's what "child" means in this context) won't have any affect.

Comment: I mean childs for the parent who locked the table (same user) .
if these childs commit work , it will affect the locking of the table?.